# angular custom input component not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-components, controlvalueaccessor

I created a custom input component for times. I can successfully set the initial value received by [(ngModel)], however any changes to the input field are not being processed.
To be more precise: writeValue gets called initially, the setter does not.

The component looks as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-timepicker',
  templateUrl: './timepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timepicker.component.scss'],
  providers: [{provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: forwardRef(() => NexupTimepickerComponent)}]
})
export class NexupTimepickerComponent implements OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {

  autofilled: boolean;

  // Subject for the changes on the input
  stateChanges = new Subject<void>();

  // Grouping of the input fields
  parts: FormGroup;

  public _onChange: any;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private fm: FocusMonitor, private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
              @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    this.parts =  fb.group({
      'hour': '',
      'minute': ''
    });

    // control focus
    fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });

    this._onChange = (_: any) => {
    };
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  // value
  @Input()
  get value(): Time | null {
    console.log('Getting value');
    const n = this.parts.value;
    if (n.hour.length === 2 && n.minute.length === 2) {
      return new Time(n.hour, n.minute);
    }
    return null;
  }

  set value(time: Time | null) {
    console.log('Setting value to: ', time);
    time = time || new Time('', '');
    this.parts.setValue({hour: time.hour, minute: time.minute});
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
    this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    console.log('registered');
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    console.log('received value: ', value);
    if ((value !== this.parts.getRawValue()) && value) {
      console.log('writing value to: ', value);
      this.parts.setValue({hour: value.hour, minute: value.minute});
      console.log('new value: ', this.parts.getRawValue());
    }
  }

}
```

The HTML in the parent component is this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>End Time</mat-label>
          <app-timepicker [required]="true"
            [(ngModel)]="endTimeObject" #endTime="ngModel" name="endTime" ngDefaultControl>
          </app-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setter: **set value**  is not called  it's normally cause you don't have change the "value" value, you should have done somethine like  **this.value = "...";**

To do this and for more control I generally add a [formControl]="myControl" on the inner input of my component (if I have one :)) and do something like this in the component :

```
myControl = new FormControl();

this.myControl.onStatusChange.subscribe( (newValue) => {
  this.value = newValue;
});
```

Futhermore it will be normal that [(ngModel)] will be not update to date cause you're never calling the this._onChange()  callback.

The registerOnChage method give you a callback that you must call when you are updating the value from inside the component to notify the ngModel/formControl. I supposed you should add in set value :

```
 set value(time: Time | null) {
    console.log('Setting value to: ', time);
    time = time || new Time('', '');
    const newValue = {hour: time.hour, minute: time.minute};
    this.parts.setValue(newValue );
    this._onChange(newValue); // call the callback :)
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
```

---

For more information here you can find a default implementation of the controlValueAccessor. You could extend this class in every component working with ngModel and simple change the value (**this.value = 'newValue'**) and also override the writeValue cause it generally need to change to feet your component needs.
https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/common/default-control-value-accessor.ts

Comment: But if that was the case, shouldn't I see the console.log even though not calling this._onChange?

Comment: the set value will be called you somewhere in your code you will do "this.value = ...;" I can't see this in your code

Comment: That is right, sorry if I was unclear. "Setting value to" is not being logged in the console.

Comment: I thought registering the change function would detect changes. Where would I set the value?

Comment: I had to fix a bit more than that to get it working, especially set the ngModelChange. Nevertheless you're idea showed me the right direction, so thank you.